# Optimization build dictionary for list of list

Tags: c#, performance, linq, list, dictionary

I have a list that contains element like (listElement): {e1,e2,e3,e4,e5,e6,e7}

They are group like that in a list of list (listOfList):
{ {e1,e2,e3,e4}, {e1,e2,e3}, {e2,e3,e4}, {e1,e2}, {e2,e3}, {e3,e4}, {e5}, {e6,e7} }

What I want is put that lists in a dictionary>> (dict) like that :

- Key,           (Value)
- e1,            ({e1,e2,e3,e4},{e1,e2,e3},{e1,e2})
- e2,            ({e1,e2,e3,e4},{e1,e2,e3},{e2,e3,e4},{e1,e2},{e2,e3})
- e3,            ({e1,e2,e3,e4},{e1,e2,e3},{e2,e3,e4},{e2,e3},{e3,e4})
- e4,            (({e1,e2,e3,e4},{e2,e3,e4},{e3,e4})
- e5,            ({e5})
  = e6,            ({e6,e7})

for now i have a code like that:

```
foreach (element in listElement){
   var elementListOfList = listOfList,where(e=>e.countain(f));
   dict[f.id] = elementListOfList;
}
```

The problem is the build of the dictionary is really too long cause i have like 1 million elements to but in the dictionary.

I know use a for over a for each can be best but I'm sure its possible to do something else.

My question is someone have an idea to optimize the creation of the dictionary, and/or some site or book that can help me with optimization of code ?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: oh sorry did not read that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every item of listElement you're iterating all the lists in ListOfList. (Contains often will stop before reaching the end of the list, but nonetheless this gives you O(k*n) time complexity, where k is the length of listElement and n is the number of all elements of all lists in ListOfLists).

Your loop is roughly equivalent to:

```
foreach (var element in listElement)
    foreach (var list in ListOfList)
        foreach (var elem in list)
            if (element == elem)
            {
                dict[elem].Add(list);
                break;
            }
```

You can improve it by iterating only once the elements of lists of ListOfLists:

```
var dict = listElement.ToDictionary(e => e, e => new List<List<YourType>>());
foreach (var list in ListOfList)
    foreach (var elem in list)
        dict[elem].Add(list);
```

This gives you O(k+n) time complexity (dictionary lookup and List.Add have amortized O(1) complexity). You *cannot* get better complexity than this for this problem.

Comment: @AgentFire no it's not. If practically the same.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you cannot do it any faster than to iterate over all your elements in all your lists, since you cannot predict which list contains which items.

But you could optimize your code a bit:

Say you have your list of lists:

```
List<List<E>> listOfList = new List<List<E>>()
{
    new List<E>() { e1, e2, e3, e4 },
    new List<E>() { e1, e2, e3 },
    ... 
};
```

Then, you could make a dictionary:

```
Dictionary<E, List<List<E>>> dic = new Dictionary<E, List<List<E>>>();
```

And here you go:

```
foreach (List<E> list in listOfList)
{
    foreach (E item in list)
    {
        List<List<E>> itemList;

        if (!dic.TryGetValue(item, out itemList))
        {
            dic[item] = itemList = new List<List<E>>();
        }

        itemList.Add(list);
    }
}
```